# Maximum length of identifier in -initWithCenter:radius:identifier: of CLCircularRegion

Tags: ios, objective-c, geofencing, region-monitoring, clcircularregion

What is the maximum length allowed for `identifier` property in 
[- initWithCenter:radius:identifier:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLCircularRegion_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLCircularRegion/initWithCenter:radius:identifier:) method of `CLCircularRegion` class used for `region monitoring`?

[- initWithCenter:radius:identifier:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLCircularRegion_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLCircularRegion/initWithCenter:radius:identifier:) is returning `nil` when the `identifier` length exceeds a certain limit. So what is that limit?

Comment: It seems like it would be pretty trivial to work it out - why don't you try?

Comment: I tried..till 511 characters it is returning the object and after that it is returning nil. But there is no documentation for it.

Comment: Right, so it seems the limit is 511 but as you say there is no documentation. That seems quite a lot for an identifier which would typically be 8 or so characters

Answer (score 0):

The max length is **512**.
If it is exceeded, I get in iOS 14 the log

```
[Client] {"msg":"identifier is too long"}
```

A longer ID fires also a runtime breakpoint.